# How to rename DataFrame header with values from mapping table in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have to rename columns of  table() with values from mapping table(df2 below) in Pyspark.

Thanks for any help!

## I tried to do it with pandas but it works for 25 min with my tables.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'kod':[1,1,3,4,5], 'freq':[4,8,8,20,16], 'lsv':[100,200,300,250,400]}) 

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'oldid':['kod','freq','lsv'], 'newid':['code','visits','volume']}) 

mapping=dict(df2[['oldid', 'newid']].values) 
df=df.rename(columns=mapping)  

display(df2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Spark Dataframes works little differently than Pandas data frame
>   after converting your pandas dataframes into Spark data frames

I am updating the name of `freq` to `zeq` just to demonstrate the sorting

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(4,1,100),(8,1,200),(8,3,300),(20,4,250),(16,5,400)], ['zeq','kod','lsv'])                
sorted_df = df.select(sorted(df.columns))
sorted_df.show()

+---+---+---+
|kod|lsv|zeq|
+---+---+---+
|  1|100|  4|
|  1|200|  8|
|  3|300|  8|
|  4|250| 20|
|  5|400| 16|
+---+---+---+
```

> header dataFrame

```
headers = spark.createDataFrame([('code','kod'),('visits','zeq'),('volume','lsv')],['newid','oldid'])
headers.show()
+------+-----+
| newid|oldid|
+------+-----+
|  code|  kod|
|visits|  zeq|
|volume|  lsv|
+------+-----+
```

there is a method called `toDF` available on Spark dataframe that takes the list of new header columns as an argument and updates the header of the dataframe.

> so sort your data frame based on oldid and select new id and convert that column values into list like below

```
sorted_headers_list = headers.sort('oldid').select('newid').rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()
```

> update your dataframe with new headers

```
df_with_updated_headers = sorted_df.toDF(*sorted_headers_list)

df_with_updated_headers.show()
+----+------+------+
|code|volume|visits|
+----+------+------+
|   1|   100|     4|
|   1|   200|     8|
|   3|   300|     8|
|   4|   250|    20|
|   5|   400|    16|
+----+------+------+
```

please let me know if you need more details

Comment: But there is a little case that horizontal order of column names in first table and vertical order of new names in second should be same. In my example  it is  [|freq|kod|lsv|]   in first table and  absolutely different order in mapping table. If there any way to rename columns with dict?

Comment: @PeterThePig I have updated the answer with your updated query.

Comment: Thanks Suresh,  I like this decision, it's very elegant.                                         
Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Comment: It helped a lot!   Thank you :)